# Problems Reading Zip of Shapefiles without loading memory

Tags: python-3.x, macos, zip, shapefile, stringio

I've been trying to adapt Andrew Gaidus shapefile reading routine for my needs.  The Jupyter Notebook I'm using acts like it partitioned the disk of my MacBook Pro so I can't read or write to disk. Gaidus has a good procedure for avoiding using disk, but is written for prior version of Python.

Here is the code:

```
    dls = "https://github.com/ItsMeLarry/Coursera_Capstone/raw/master/tl_2010_25009_tract00%202.zip"
lynntracts = ZipFile(io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(dls).read()))
print("Done")

filenames = [y for y in sorted(lynntracts.namelist()) for ending in ['dbf', 'prj', 'shp', 'shx'] if y.endswith(ending)] 
#For some reason, I get 8, instead of 4, filenames.  The first 4 start with __MACOSX. I get rid of those. The problem I
#have with the 'TypeError' occurs no matter which set of 4 files I use.
print(filenames[0], 'Example of the 4 files that I remove in the for loop')
for i in range(0,4):
     del filenames[0]
print(filenames)
dbf, prj, shp, shx = [io.StringIO(ZipFile.read(filename)) for filename in filenames]
r = shapefile.Reader(shp=shp, shx=shx, dbf=dbf)
print(r.numRecords)
```

Opening with io.BytesIO cured the prior problem of byte/str collision. Now see the TypeError for the ZipFile.read.  I get the same error if I use io.BytesIO when calling it.  Here is error output followed by error info:

Done
__MACOSX/tl_2010_25009_tract00/._tl_2010_25009_tract00.dbf Example of the 4 files that I remove in the for loop

### ['tl_2010_25009_tract00/tl_2010_25009_tract00.dbf', 'tl_2010_25009_tract00/tl_2010_25009_tract00.prj', 'tl_2010_25009_tract00/tl_2010_25009_tract00.shp', 'tl_2010_25009_tract00/tl_2010_25009_tract00.shx']

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     12      del filenames[0]
     13 print(filenames)
---> 14 dbf, prj, shp, shx = [io.StringIO(ZipFile.read(filename)) for filename in filenames]
     15 r = shapefile.Reader(shp=shp, shx=shx, dbf=dbf)
     16 print(r.numRecords)

in (.0)
     12      del filenames[0]
     13 print(filenames)
---> 14 dbf, prj, shp, shx = [io.StringIO(ZipFile.read(filename)) for filename in filenames]
     15 r = shapefile.Reader(shp=shp, shx=shx, dbf=dbf)
     16 print(r.numRecords)

TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Clearly, I am a beginner. I've come up empty handed trying to research this.  Where do I go?  What do I need to understand here? Thanks

Comment: `TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'` it means you have mistake in `ZipFile.read()` - it needs more arguments. Find documentation for `ZipFile` and check `ZipFile.read()`. It may need two elements - name of zip file and name of readed file. Or it may need `ZipFile('some.zip').read(filename)` or `lynntracts.read(filename)`